# Как вставить интерактивную иконку вместо кнопки QRadioButton?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside2, qradiobutton, paintevent

Как мне заменить обычную кнопку `QRadioButton` на иконку.

```
...

    self.radioButton = QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.radioButton.setObjectName(u"radioButton")
    self.radioButton.setGeometry(QRect(50, 30, 111, 101))
    icon = QIcon()
    icon.addFile(u"3.svg", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
    icon.addFile(u"2.svg", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.On)
    self.radioButton.setIcon(icon)

...
```

Код был сгенерирован программой *Qt Designer*.

Но я не совсем понимаю, почему иконка не меняется  после нажатия на радио и как вообще скрыть дефолтную иконку `QRadioButton`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

чтобы потом заменить ее иконкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае надо переопределять метод `paintEvent` 
в классе наследованном от `QRadioButton`.

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QRadioButton, QHBoxLayout, QButtonGroup, 
    QApplication, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class RadioButton(QRadioButton): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(RadioButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.pixmap         = QPixmap("LightOff.png")
        self.pixmap_pressed = QPixmap("lightOn.png")
        self.setText('rb0')

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.isChecked():                                   
            pix = self.pixmap_pressed
        else:
            pix = self.pixmap
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(event.rect(), pix)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(30, 30)      


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self._dictRB = {                                            
            'rb0': False,
            'rb1': False,
            'rb2': False,
            'rb3': False,
        }

        self.main_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.buttonGroup = QButtonGroup()
        self.attr_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.attr_layout)


        self.rb0 = RadioButton()                             #QRadioButton() # 'rb0'
        self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.rb0)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb0)

        self.rb1 = QRadioButton('rb1')
        self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.rb1)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb1)               

        self.rb2 = QRadioButton('rb2')
        self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.rb2)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb2) 

        self.rb3 = QRadioButton('rb3')                               
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb3)                         

        self.buttonGroup.buttonClicked.connect(self.check_button)

    def check_button(self, radioButton):
        if self._dictRB[radioButton.text()]:
            self._dictRB[radioButton.text()] = False
            self._dictRB['rb3'] = True
            self.rb3.setChecked(True)              
        else:
            for b in self._dictRB:
                self._dictRB[b] = False
            self._dictRB[radioButton.text()] = True

        print("Нажата кнопка -> `{} - {}`".format(radioButton.text(), radioButton.isChecked()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]